# Only convert string representation of number to number in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `Dataframe` and I realize when my `Dataframe` columns only have string representation of numbers then the conversion will take place, otherwise it will not. The code below I am using to convert all numbers that are in string form to numbers.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['3', 'r'], 1: ['1', 's']})
df = df.apply(partial(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore'))
```

The code above will not work, because `'r'` and `'s'` are in columns. So everything will remain as strings. How can I get the code to convert `'3'` and `'1'` to numbers `3` and `1`?

Comment: You can't. A column has a single datatype. You can't represent letters as a number, so that datatype can't be numeric.

Comment: Is that so? Thank you for letting me know. I did not know that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@MadPhysicist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241792/only-convert-string-representation-of-number-to-number-in-pandas#comment91432115_52241792) states, Pandas.Series have a single `dtype`.  However, that `dtype` can be `object` which means anything goes.  You'll lose **MANY** advantages from having a numeric `dtype` but it might be what you want.

#### Force non-numeric things to `NaN`

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

     0    1
0  3.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN
```

**NOTE:**
`apply` iterates through each column and passes that column through the `callable` that was given.  That means that each column got a treatment like this:

```
pd.to_numeric(one_of_the_columns, errors='coerce')
```

Using `errors='coerce'` makes things numbers where it can and `np.nan` otherwise.

---

#### Use `dtype` object and throw away efficiency for... whatever it is you're trying to do

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))
df

   0  1
0  3  1
1  r  s
```

To validate that it actually changed `3` to a number try:

```
df.applymap(type)

                       0                      1
0  <class 'numpy.int64'>  <class 'numpy.int64'>
1          <class 'str'>          <class 'str'>
```

**NOTE:**
`applymap` iterates through each *cell* of the dataframe and passes that cell's value through the `callable` passed.  In this case, each cell was treated like:

```
pd.to_numeric(one_particular_cell, errors='ignore')
```

And was turned into a number if possible otherwise left alone.

This is inefficient but does what you want.  As Pandas tries to reconcile the damage you've done, it realizes that there are mixed types in some columns and changes the `dtype` to `object` in order to accomodate.